# QT QML change state c++

Tags: qt, qml

i've a MouseArea that call a signal, 
i plug this signal to a slot and it's working, my c++ code is running.

But is it possible inside c++ code, change the QML state ?

code of button that call signal (OK) :

```
MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        inscriptionCarre.qmlSignalButtonInscription("Button");
                    }
                }
```

Code of my states :

```
states: [
    State {
        name: "start";
        PropertyChanges { target: home; x: -master.width; }
        PropertyChanges { target: login; x:0; }
    },
    State {
        name: "loginOK";
        PropertyChanges { target: login; x: -master.width; }
        PropertyChanges { target: liste; x:0; }
    }
]
```

I would like inside my slot (c++ code) change state to "loginOK", is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since state is an item property, you should be able to modify it like so:

```
QDeclarativeEngine engine;
QDeclarativeComponent component(&engine, "MyItem.qml");
QObject *object = component.create();
object->setProperty("state", "loginOK");
```

Reference: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtbinding.html#modifying-properties

Or from your C++ slot you could emit a signal that passes the state string to a QML slot that in turn sets the state. For example like:

C++ file:

```
...
signals:
     void stateChanged(const QString &newState);
...
```

QML file:

```
...
MyItem {
     onStateChanged: {
         state: newState
     }
}
...
```

Comment: Question: I assume you do `emit stateChanged("loginOK");` after `object->setProperty("state", "loginOK");`. You don't mention how to bind the signal to the QML slot. Can you please provide the information. I use `Connections { ... }` for connecting C++ signals to QML slots but in this case this doesn't trigger the change in the UI (since in my case based on the new state the item changes (for example the `color` of a `Rectangle` item). The slot does get triggered only when using `Connections { ... }`. Otherwise nothing happens. Any idea?

Comment: Nevermind. I managed to fix it. Indeed in the latest Qt one has to use the `Connections` item. However when called from C++ the state of all visible items in the list changes. In order to prevent that one has to specify that only the `currentItem.state` needs to be set to the new state.